# pandas.read_sql_query with sqlite3 returns an Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to retrieve the data using an API call and use the data to do the Collaborative Filtering
Here's my Python code:

```
def getRecommendations(databaseLocation, uid):
con = sqlite3.connect(databaseLocation)
query = '''SELECT * FROM viewTABLE;'''
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM viewTABLE;", con)
dataPrep = df[['uid', 'recipeId', 'isView']]
print(df)
con.close()
return get_recommendations(dataPrep).loc[[uid]].values.tolist()[0]
```

It returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, uid, recipeId, isView]
Index: []
```

It's definitely not SQLite connection problem since it returns correct columns but without any data in it

Comment: Try removing the semicolon. SQL in general allows you to make multiple queries, each separated by colon, but not all libraries support it, so it's possible you see the result from the last (empty) query.

Comment: The problem still occur after removing the semicolon. I think read_sql_query got the right query since it returns with the correct column names.